# How to make vue swipeable bottom sheet component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

i want to make swipeable bottom sheet component, like this https://manufont.github.io/react-swipeable-bottom-sheet/scroll.html

I have also tried this package https://github.com/atsutopia/vue-swipeable-bottom-sheet
but this package not to sweep in all sheets areas.

and i try to do something with vue-recognizer to catch pan events , but it end up like this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      class="fixed bg-white rounded w-full text-center"
      v-recognizer:pan.end="onPanEnd"
      :style="{bottom: '0px', height: height + 'px'}"
      v-recognizer:pan.up="onPanUp"
      v-recognizer:pan.down="onPanDown"
      style="z-index:1000;"
    >
      <div class="py-4">{{height}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      height: 92,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onPanUp() {
      this.height = parseInt(this.height + 5);
    },
    onPanDown() {
      this.height = parseInt(this.height - 5);
    },
    onPanEnd() {
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

any suggestions ?